# Generate csv file report with pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Is it possible somehow generate the test execution report in csv file?
I use python, selenium, pytest.
Any advise would be appreciated!

Comment: No, but you can probably convert the xml or json (separate module) outputs pretty easily.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Ok I'll try to search:) thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [pytest-excel](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-excel/) to generate xls file report.

Usage:

`pip install pytest-excel
pytest --excelreport=report.xls`

It will generate report.xls excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [pytest-csv](https://github.com/nicoulaj/pytest-csv) plugin, hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me:

`pip install  pytest-csv`


`pytest --csv=report.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytest's [plugin API](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html) to do so - see e.g. [pytest-json](https://github.com/mattcl/pytest-json) for something similar.