# How to create custom test report (csv or excel format) for python pytest test

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I am using pytest to run my test with below command and report is generated in html format.I have used hookwrapper in conftest.py for html report.

```
Code to run the test :
py.test --html=report.html --self-contained-html test.py
```

I want to know if there is a way to generate custom report in csv or excel format using python pytest

Answer (score 1):

From my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012773/2312300):

> I have been using pytest-excel plugin to generate xls file report.
>
> Usage:
>
> pip install pytest-excel
>
> pytest --excelreport=report.xls
>
> It will generate report.xls excel file.